# Is possible to customize positive and negative buttons in AlertDialog?

Tags: android, android-widget

Is possible to customize positive and negative buttons in AlertDialog ?
I need to replace default look of positive and negative with custom.

```
.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {...
.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {...
```

Can somebody tell me how to do that ?

Comment: You'll have to create a custom dialog box. :/ Here is the simplest tutorial I could find. http://i.thiyagaraaj.com/articles/android-articles/customdialogboxpopupusinglayoutinandroid

Answer (score 6):

```
public class ComentarDialog extends DialogFragment{

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    builder.setMessage("Mensaje de alerta")
           .setTitle("Comentar")
           .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton("CANCELAR", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

               }
           });

    return builder.create();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    //Personalizamos

    Resources res = getResources();

    //Buttons
    Button positive_button =  ((AlertDialog) getDialog()).getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
    positive_button.setBackground(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_selector_dialog));

    Button negative_button =  ((AlertDialog) getDialog()).getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
    negative_button.setBackground(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_selector_dialog));

    int color = Color.parseColor("#304f5a");

    //Title
    int titleId = res.getIdentifier("alertTitle", "id", "android");
    View title = getDialog().findViewById(titleId);
    if (title != null) {
        ((TextView) title).setTextColor(color);
    }

    //Title divider
    int titleDividerId = res.getIdentifier("titleDivider", "id", "android");
    View titleDivider = getDialog().findViewById(titleDividerId);
    if (titleDivider != null) {
        titleDivider.setBackgroundColor(color);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: FYI `button.setBackground()` ... requires API level 16

Answer (score 4):

Yuo can set every view in dialog box. You can set view with two buttons and dont set positive & negative buttons.

example:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = 
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

View dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(this)
            .inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null);

builder.setView(dialogView);
```

Comment: out of context!

Comment: @Jivraj S Shekhawat Ok, whatever. If you can provide a better answer so please do that

Answer (score 3):

if you want to customize you can use dialog instead of alert dialog
here is the sample code

```
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ThisweekActivity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar);
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(ThisweekActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.issue_cover_prompt_layout, null);
    view.findViewById(R.id.close_btn).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.issue_cover_img);
    img.setImageBitmap(issue.getCoverImage());

    dialog.setContentView(view);
    dialog.show();
```

you can set set the layout in dialog and add click listner on it

Answer (score 1):

if you want to change them, I will suggest using activity with your required layout and add them= Dialog in your activity, in Manifest file